# .gitignore, исключение в игнорировании файлов

Tags: git

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется следующая структура:

> ```
> Корень \
>         Logs\
>              Nginx\
>                    файлы логов.
>                    .gitkeep
>              Users\
>                    файлы логов.
>                    .gitkeep
> ```

Мне необходимо сохранить структуру папок, но чтобы в git не попадали сами файлы логов. Как это можно сделать? Мне необходимо просто оставить пустые папки по пути Logs\Nginx и Logs\Users.

Comment: надо файл `.gitignore` где будет строка `*`  и `!.gitignore`

Comment: Добавление `* !.gitignore !.gitkeep`
Помогло, спасибо.

Comment: сам файл gitkeep и его упоминание оного в игноре можно убирать. потому что этот файл нужен только если папка всегда пуста. на сколько я помню. Это несколько может смущать, зачем тогда нужен gitkeep)) но в целом он уже не нужен

Comment: Можно даже просто одну звёздочку (`*`) в `.gitignore`. И добавить этот файл в отслеживаемые с флагом `--force`. Git игнорирует игнорирование отслеживаемых файлов :-)